# Git internal pack view

Tags: git

Guys, question about git internals.

I can view packs content by executing:
git verify-pack -v   .git/objects/pack/pack-79b6e1ec4077aa90fd3231be780e6cc22a8e35f7.idx

It will return my content, like this one:
...
2278dd6b6ec2365c03257d153f281943f84f5ff9 blob   24 34 6110
...

How can I view the content of this piece in pack file?
git cat-file -p 2278dd is not that I want - this will show me full content. And I would like to see exactly info from part file

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "content" vs. "full content"?

Comment: Hi, put it this way - I would like to see those 24 bytes in pack file.

Comment: Well column 5 is the offset of that data in the pack file so you can pull it out with `tail -c XXX <packfile> | head -c YYY`. That data won't be the content of the blob, though.

Comment: pulling out is clear - is that data archived? which algorithm?

Comment: The format is described in the [git documentation](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/technical/pack-format.txt). If anything is not sufficiently clear you can always look at the source code.